# wrong if statement evaluation, document.cookie

Tags: javascript, if-statement, cookies

I`m trying to perform some action with document.cookie, 
I checking some If conditional mentioned below:

```
if((!document.cookie.indexOf('cookies:all_checked') >= 0) ||
   (!document.cookie.indexOf('cookies:first_and_second') != -1) ||
   (!document.cookie.indexOf('cookies:first_and_third') != -1) ||
   (!document.cookie.indexOf('cookies:first_only') != -1)){    
    createCookies();   
}
```

before this statement I create cookie like this

```
var variable = document.cookie == 'cookies:all_checked'
```

the trouble is no matter I`m trying do check

```
(!document.cookie.indexOf('cookies:all_checked') >= 0)
```

or the same without ! mark I get true with this condition. How to check is it cookies with this content is really setted?

Comment: try `!(document.cookie.indexOf('...') >= 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that

```
document.cookie.indexOf('cookies:all_checked')
```

will return either the index, or `-1` (when not found).

In your example, it will return `0` because `document.cookie` **starts with** the string you're looking for.

Then, `!0` will evaluate to `true` as `0` evaluates to `false`, and `true` evaluates to `1`, which is indeed `>= 0`.

And `0` is also `>= 0`.

That's why you get `true` everytime.

You should try:

```
!(document.cookie.indexOf('...') >= 0) // false
  document.cookie.indexOf('...') >= 0  // true
```

---

Note that `!anyNumber` will result in either `true` or `false` which will both be `>= 0` as `true` will evaluate to `1` and `false` to `0` which are both `>= 0`

Therefore, `!anyNumber >= 0` will always be `true`.

---

As a side note, please be aware that:

```
var variable = document.cookie == 'cookies:all_checked'
```

does **not** set/create your `cookie`.

What it does is check whether `cookie` equals `'cookies:all_checked'` and assigns this result (`true` or `false`) to `variable`.